# MacBook Pro NOT syncing desktop to iCloud

Tags: icloud

UPDATE: After months of doing research and trying a vast array of different things I finally decided to call Apple. I was on the phone with them for over 2 hours and they could not figure it out. Finally they had me download some special software that would scan my computer  and then they'd have it analyzed by an engineer. Then this morning when I woke up, lo and behold it was magically working! I'm thinking they may have done something server side for me. But ya thats what it took to get it working again.

TDLR: Call Apple to get it fixed.

OLD POST:
My MacBook Pro is not uploading or downloading its desktop to iCloud. It works flawlessly on my iMac, iPhone, iPad, ec...

I can't figure out what the heck is going on, here are somethings that I've tried,

- 1) signed out of iCloud, shutdown computer and waited for a few hours
- 2) unchecked and rechecked desktop & document syncing
- 3) checked to make sure I have enough space in iCloud (I do)
- 4) checked to make sure I have enough space on my computer (I do)

How can I fix this!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of doing research and trying a vast array of different things I finally decided to call Apple. I was on the phone with them for over 2 hours and they could not figure it out. Finally they had me download some special software that would scan my computer and then they'd have it analyzed by an engineer. Then this morning when I woke up, lo and behold it was magically working! I'm thinking they may have done something server side for me. But ya thats what it took to get it working again.

TDLR: Call Apple to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have desktop syncing on?
In System preferences>iCloud>iCloud Drive
Make sure its Check
Then look at the options for 'Desktop & Documents Folders' and check

You can check iCloud stats at sidebar, iCloud Drive folder will get charging circle while loading

Comment: yep, I've check all that stuff. Nothing works...would you happen to know how to delete the iCloud plist? I might have to do that

Comment: No, I have no idea- sorry. Last time I had a similar issue with PC not syncing, but it work after a day or two, I even call apple and they suggest me to wait.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Trent, well, did anything happen? I've been waiting a long time, and nothing happening here. I no longer get the progress circle or status info... definatly broken here for Desktop and Documents, but everything else in iCloud Drive is syncing just fine.

Comment: Hey man, so heres what happened. After months of doing research and trying a vast array of different things I finally decided to call Apple. I was on the phone with them for over 2 hours and they could not figure it out. Finally they had me download some special software that would scan my computer  and then they'd have it analyzed by an engineer. Then this morning when I woke up, lo and behold it was magically working! I'm thinking they may have done something server side for me. But ya thats what it took to get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally iCloud doesn't sync desktop items but you can try to place in the desktop folder in the iCloud drive folder in-oder to sync it's contents with iCloud

Comment: Yes if you have macOS Sierra your desktop will automatically sync to iCloud if you have it enable. Its an amazing feature that I've used for months before one day it mysteriously stopped working.

Comment: @SamTrent I would recommend you to hard reset your MacBook using a bootable USB  Stick or Internet Recovery, after fully formatting Macintosh HD in recovery mode!